# Django AppRegistryNotReady Exception after import from django.contrib.auth.models

Tags: django, testing, import

Here is my folder structure:

```
.
├── app
├── project
├── scripts
└── tests
    ├── fuctional -> test_views.py
    └── unit
```

Here is my test_script.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

from rest_framework.test import APIClient

from mrx.views import LoginView, LogoutView
```

When I launch `python -m unittest tests/fuctional/test_views.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/unittest/main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/edx/PycharmProjects/mrx_3/tests/fuctional/test_views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/edx/.pyenv/versions/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I've tried with import Django and then `django.setup()` and it works but:
why I can't import from `django.contrib.auth.models import User` ?

How do you test outside a Django app code inside a Django app?

Edit:

I've also tried with pytest, using **init**.py with import Django and then `django.setup()` but I still got an error:

```
(MRX) edx@edx-VirtualBox:~/PycharmProjects/mrx_3$ pytest tests/fuctional/test_views.py 
=========================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/edx/PycharmProjects/mrx_3
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                               

================================================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/fuctional/test_views.py ______________________________________________________________________________
tests/fuctional/test_views.py:7: in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py:2: in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py:48: in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:108: in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:253: in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/MRX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:136: in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
E   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
========================================================================================= short test summary info =========================================================================================
ERROR tests/fuctional/test_views.py - django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================ 1 error in 0.95s =============================================================================================
```

It seems there is a problem with some path of the pyenv: I've tried `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mrx_proj.settings` but with no success.

Comment: I've tried with __init__.py in tests folder, with  import Django and then django.setup(), and it works; but I still wondering if there is a better solution... Where do you put your tests, it's ok for Django to keep tests outside the app? I've also tried to use the script inside tests.py in the app module, but I've the same issue reported in the error screen.

Comment: I've also tried with pytest, and also with the __init__.py with django.setup() i get this error

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is to configure the test runner the proper way:

The settings need to point to Django Settings: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings

[pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Django Testing](http://django-standalone-apps.com/part1/testing.html)